# AJAX Data String Formatting / Text() Use

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX call, the data parameter is formatted as such:

```
//Removed For Brevity
data: JSON.stringify({FOO_ID:'5359d34c-6039-4b6c-95d4-038660705624',FOO_TEST:$('#FOO_TEST_81').text()}),
//Removed For Brevity
```

Where FOO_ID is being passed across correctly, and can be seen in the corresponding webmethod. FOO_TEST is reading a textbox, and always returns "Empty".

When FOO_TEST is only specified, it appears to work.

Is there a problem with the above in how it is formatted?

Answer (score 0):

If `#FOO_TEST_81` is a textbox (i.e., `input type=text` or `textarea`), it should be `$('#FOO_TEST_81').val()` rather than `$('#FOO_TEST_81').text()`.

`.text()` would work on a `textarea` if there is text inside the `<textarea></textarea>` tags but it will only read the original text, not necessarily the current value.

The strange thing is the part about it working when only `FOO_TEST` is specified... it would be a bit of a mystery if that's really the case.

Comment: If I switch to val, it just comes across as an empty string.

Comment: Save the stringified data to a variable before you call $.ajax so that you can inspect it. This should help figure out whether the problem is in JavaScript or somewhere else.